# CSS-backgroundImage preloading

Tags: css, background-image, preload

I have 2 divs for something like slideshow and about 10 slideshow images. I read many tutorials how to make preloading of these images, but I still cant get it working :(
I'm newbie at jQuery, so this code may contain maaany bicycles))
Hope you could help me to figure out whats wrong.

```
$(function () {
    var mainDiv = $("#homeBanner");
    var secondDiv = $("#homeBanner2");
    var aImages = [];
    var imgCount = 10;
    var iRnd = 0;


    $(document).ready(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i <= imgCount; i++) {
            aImages[i] = new Image();
            aImages[i].src = "url-to-image" + (i) + ".jpeg";
        }
        setInterval(function () {

            if (iRnd < imgCount) {
                iRnd++;
            } else {
                iRnd = 0;
            }

            secondDiv.queue(function () {
                mainDiv.css("background-image", 'url(' + aImages[iRnd].src + ')');
                secondDiv.dequeue();
            });

            secondDiv.animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, 2000, "swing");
            secondDiv.queue(function () {
                secondDiv.css("background-image", 'url(' + aImages[iRnd].src + ')');
                secondDiv.dequeue();
            });

            secondDiv.animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 0);

        }, 3000);

    });
});
```

Comment: Instead of trusting the `setInterval` why you don't use the `onload` listener? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Using_images

Comment: So, you think that problem is in `setInterval`?

Comment: No, but just random waiting and expecting the image is loaded is not a good way.. Also you have 2 times `$(document).ready()`

Comment: I just dont understand why they dont preloading.
`for (var i = 0; i <= imgCount; i++) {aImages[i] = new Image();....`
seems to work and I see many examples with this issue.
But `.css("background-image"...)` seems like loading images again from scratch. 
Unfortunately I dont know how to make slideshow other then with `setInterval`. I read about unload, but didn't figure out how to use it yet.